# How to read data from a table in MySQL from java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

2 problems, it outputs `1 2 3 4 3 5`, instead of `1 2 3 4 5`, which I'm not sure why followed by success but does not print out the data from the SQL table

```
Statement st = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
try {
    System.out.println("1");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

    System.out.println("2");

    //Class.forName(driver);

    System.out.println("3");

    st = con.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT productcost " +
        "FROM producttable " +
        "WHERE productid = 3;");

    System.out.println("4");
    if (rs.next()) { //get first result
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)); //coloumn 1
    }

    System.out.println("5");

    System.out.println("Success");

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Error");
}
```

Comment: can you write more details about your problem .. maybe it output `1 2 3 4 3 5 Success` because of `productcost` from the query is equal to `3`

Comment: Why did you expect it not to print something between `4` and `5`, when you have a `println(rs.getInt(1))` between them. Why do you say it *"does not print out the data from the sql table"* when it prints the value `3`, i.e. the value of `productcost`? Perhaps if you changed print statement to something like `println("productcost = " + rs.getInt(1))`, you'd recognize your own output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are seeing `3` in-between `4` and `5` is because the ResultSet contains `3`.

[ResultSet.getInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int))

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this ResultSet object as an int

Try debugging your code and stepping through that section. You'll see what I am displaying below.

[image]

Comment: @Andreas lol! corrected! RS in my world == ADODB.Recordset. Heavily used in many of our legacy applications at work.

Comment: Thank you so much!! Cannot believe i did not realise that

Answer (score -1):

You must have '3' as a data in first column! Cause your printing the data of first column of record.i don't see any problem here!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer. It’s because of helpful peers like yourself that we’re able to learn together as a community. Here are a few tips on how to make your answer great: [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Brien, thank you for the information. I'm still new to this platform. I will try to improve myself over the time!